# How to keep my UDF from acting on more than one worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

So  I'm trying to create a function that will automatically write one range of values to another, different range of cells.  I have the function working just fine, but a problem arises when I start using INDIRECT() to pass it the arguments.

```
Public Function TranscribeRng(ReadInRng As Range, CopyToRng As Range)
If AreRngsEqual(ReadInRng, CopyToRng) = True Then
    Dim r As Long
    r = 0
    Dim c As Long
    c = 0
    
    While c < ReadInRng.Columns.Count
        r = 0
        While r < ReadInRng.Rows.Count
            
            Evaluate "TranscribeValueRNG(" & ReadInRng.Cells(r + 1, c + 1).Address(False, False) & "," & CopyToRng.Cells(r + 1, c + 1).Address(False, False) & ")"
            
            r = r + 1
            Wend
        c = c + 1
    Wend
    
    TranscribeRng = ReadInRng.Address(False, False) & " writing to " & CopyToRng.Address(False, False)
    
Else
    TranscribeRng = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If
End Function


Private Sub TranscribeValueRNG(ReadValue As Range, CopyToCell As Range)
    CopyToCell.Value = ReadValue
    
End Sub
```

This works fine when the ReadInRng and CopyToRng arguments are passed in as normal A1:B2 references (ex. =TranscribeRng(A1:B2,C1:D2) ), but when I use this function with INDIRECT() cell references (ex. =TranscribeRng(INDIRECT("A1:B2",True),INDIRECT("C1:D2",True)) ) its behavior becomes a real problem.

when using INDIRECT cell references, the functions try to act on ALL the worksheets in the workbook.  To elaborate, when using this function on "Sheet1", entering a value in cell A1 of "Sheet1", the TranscribeRng function will copy that value to cell C1 on "Sheet1" as intended.  HOWEVER, when I then flip over to "Sheet2" and enter a value into cell A1 on "Sheet2", that value will ALSO be copied over into cell C1 on "Sheet2", EVEN THO the TranscribeRng function is only present on "Sheet1".

This does not happen when I use normal cell references (ex. A1:B2).  In that case, the function does not act upon Sheets it's not supposed to.  Only when I throw in the INDIRECT() references does it start acting on all sheets all the time.

I've tried adding a line

```
Application.Volatile(False)
```

into the code and this stops it from *actively* copying over values, by which I mean that the function only operates when its host cell is *manually* recalculated (even with the INDIRECT() references).  But then when I try to have its host cell recalculated via another process like a Worksheet Change Event or a Sub like

```
Sub ReCalc(Host as range)
   Host.calculate
End Sub
```

nothing happens.  I can't seem to get the Volatile(False) version to automatically recalculate.  It only happens when I manually click on the cell then hit enter.

Tho I realize there might be a way to have Excel copy over data like this without packaging it into a User Defined Function, I really want to keep this as a function so I can move it about on my worksheet and use it in all the usual function ways.

I've been stuck on this problem for almost a week now and it's really driving me crazy.  Any advice you can offer would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Untested, but try `ReadInRng.Parent.Evaluate` instead of just `Evaluate`.

Comment: Holy smokes!  I think it worked!  Thanks so much for your help.  I amended the line 'Evaluate "TranscribeValueRNG...'
to 
'ReadInRng.Parent.Evaluate TranscribeValueRNG...' 
and that seems to do the trick.  Just out of curiosity, could you explain the difference between these two?  Why does one work and the other not, and how does the ReadInRng.Parent addition change the Evaluate statement?

Comment: `Evaluate` operates in the context of the activesheet... `Worksheet.Evaluate` specifies the worksheet.